# what is the difference between "" and '' in unsigned char name='1'; ("1")

Tags: c, char, hex, unsigned, double-quotes

What is the difference between single quotes and double quotes in the below code:

```
    unsigned char name='1';
    unsigned char name1="1";
    printf("name in hex name=%x, name1=%x\n",name,name1);
    printf("name in ascii name=%d, name1=%d\n",name,name1);
```

the output is as below:

```
 name in hex name=31, name1=18
 name in ascii name=49 name1=24
```

Comment: the difference is that the second one is UB...

Comment: What did you do to find the answer yourself? What **specifically** did you not understand in you C book? Why don't you pay heed to the compiler warning (or why did you not enable warnings as recommended e.g. on the info page here?

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Constraint violation, actually.

Comment: The warning from MSVC about `unsigned char name1="1";` is *"warning C4047: 'initializing' : `unsigned char` differs in levels of indirection from `char [2]`"*